# Iterar em Map<List, String>

Tags: flutter, dart

Como iterar em uma `Map`do tipo `Map<List, String>`?
Listar todos os valores, pagar o valor da chave: `[1, 'A']`.

```
void main() {
  print(_mapList.map);
  //??
  // _mapList.map((i, s) =>{

  // });
}

Map<List, String> _mapList = {
  [1, 'A']: "1A",
  [2, 'B']: "2A"
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para listar todos os elementos:

```
  _mapList.entries.forEach((entry) {
    print('${entry.key}: ${entry.value}');
  });
// resultado: 
// [1, A]: 1A
// [2, B]: 2A
```

Para pegar o valor da chave `[1, 'A']` não é tão trivial, pois a chave é uma lista (e muito bem explicado pelo @Matheus Ribeiro).

Então, uma solução seria forçar uma busca pelos elementos da chave, dentro das entradas do mapa:

```
  final value = _mapList.entries.firstWhere((entry) => entry.key[0] == 1 && entry.key[1] == 'A').value;
  print(value); // 1A
```

Ou se isso for usado muitas vezes, encapsular num método auxiliar:

```
  String _getListElementFromMap(Map<List, String> map, int firstElement, String secondElement) {
    return map.entries.firstWhere((entry) => entry.key[0] == firstElement && entry.key[1] == secondElement).value;
  } 

  print(_getListElementFromMap(_mapList, 1, 'A')); // 1A
  print(_getListElementFromMap(_mapList, 2, 'B')); // 2A
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu já passei por esse problema um tempo atrás e buscando nas classes internas achei o seguinte:

> ```
>   /**
>    * Creates a Map instance with the default implementation, [LinkedHashMap].
>    *
>    * This constructor is equivalent to the non-const map literal `<K,V>{}`.
>    *
>    * A `LinkedHashMap` requires the keys to implement compatible
>    * `operator==` and `hashCode`, and it allows null as a key.
>    * It iterates in key insertion order.
>    */
> ```

Nesse hint diz que as *Key* precisam ser compatíveis com o operador `==` e uma `List` não é compatível.

Então sempre que tu fizer `_mapList[[1, 'A']]` vai receber um *NULL* como resposta.

**Exemplo**

Segue um exemplo para melhor entender:

```
void main() {
  List a = [1, 2];
  List b = [1, 2];

  String c = "Teste";
  String d = "Teste";

  print(a == b); // return false
  print(c == d); // return true
}
```

Você pode rodar no [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/).

**WorkAround**

Quando me deparei com isso, acabei transformando minha `List` em uma `String` e trabalhando com ela dessa maneira...

Você pode inserir no seu `Map` a *Key* como um texto `"[1, 'B']": "1B"` e se precisar depois trabalhar com a *Key* no formato de lista, basta fazer

```
jsonDecode(Key); // Return [1, 'B'] (List)
```

Answer (score 1):

Como uma outra sugestão à outra resposta, você pode usar o método [forEach](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-core/Map/forEach.html) para iterar sobre todos os elementos de um Map:

```
 Map<List, String> _mapList = {
    [1, 'A']: "1A",
    [2, 'B']: "2A"
  };


  _mapList.forEach((k, v) {
       print(k);
       print(v);
   });
```

Se você quer comparar e descobrir o valor de uma chave específica, outro workaround é você usar as funções da classe [ListEquality](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/ListEquality-class.html) (*Note o import no começo*):

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

 Map<List, String> _mapList = {
    [1, 'A']: "1A",
    [2, 'B']: "2A"
  };


_mapList.forEach((k, v) {
       if(ListEquality().equals(k, [1,'A']))
           print (v);
   });
```

Tenha em mente que essa é uma solução que obrigatoriamente itera sobre todos os elementos do dicionário, então você vai **perder** a característica de tempo médioconstante de acesso. A complexidade do tempo de acesso vai mudar de `O(1)` para `O(n)`. Logo, pode demorar mais para dicionários maiores.